# "Service worker" and notifications when the POST request is cached

Tags: vue.js, vuex, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have create a PWA with VueJS and the plugin `workbox`.
The user can navigate in the application if is offline with the service worker cache.

I cache the request `POST` and `PATCH` if the user is offline, but I would like notify the user in this case.

If I use `import` or `require` the service worker sends a error message so I cannot use the VueX store to display a message.

Anyone have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't cache HTTP beside GET. Are you caching in IndexedDB?

Comment: @ChrisLove yes the request is cached in IndexedDB, but I would like notify the user when the cached request sent.

Comment: You would need to post a message from the service worker to client, with the client UI having the appropriate code to catch and process the message. Since your code will trigger the POST you have control over the workflow.
I am assuming you are caching due to the device being offline and you can't POST. I do this sort of thing all the time for my clients.